# Piezoelectric circular plate resonant frequency

Tags: frequency, piezoelectric

I was trying to make a project where I was using piezoelectric. I gave him vibration by making some noise around here, and when I saw the output at DSO, it showed me 49 Hz. but I need resonant frequency in the output. The resonant frequency is 4.6 kHz. Anyone have any idea how to do it?